# Zabbix for Solr Profiling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solr, profiling, windows-server-2008, zabbix

Not sure whether this can be done or not? Or may be someone has already done this.

I want to monitor application, specifically Solr on Zabbix? Its on Windows Server. Zabbix monitor JVM and there isn't issue for this. Does it provide profile information like any application profiler with execution time details?

Moreover, I have asp.net c# mvc3 application as well on the same server. Can I monitor / profile that as well using Zabbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We monitor Solr using Zabbix very effectively by using the JMX features in Zabbix 2.0 and above. Follow the instructions for setting up [JMX with Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring) and then point to your Solr instances. JMX is enabled by default in Solr.